# Updating input elements with properties of a C# object in Javascript without Ajax?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Depending on the selected value of a combobox I want to update some input elements in a form. The combobox is populated with a `List<Person>` which is passed via ViewBag from the controller:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Person, new SelectList(ViewBag.Persons, "Id", "Name"), "Choose", new { id = "comboBox" })
```

Now I am wondering if it is possible to update the elements without doing an Ajax request:

```
$(function () {
    $('#comboBox').change(function () {
        var person = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
        document.getElementById("Age").value = person.Age; // fault!
    });
});
```

So in other words: is there a way to pass a .Net object to JavaScript? Maybe by an additional library? Or do I loose all information by creating the `SelectList` for the combobox?

Comment: Encode the whole object as [JSON](http://json.org/), then print it into your js code.

Answer (score 1):

`person` is a `HTMLOptionElement`. It doesn't have a `Age` property. You can access the `text` and `value` properties.

`document.getElementById("Age").value = person.value;`

Insert a Javascript array of Person objects in your page then you could get the selected `Person` by Id and use the `Age` property from it as needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var people = [{"id": 1, "name": "foo", "age": 10}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar", "age": 20}, {"id": 3, "name": "baz", "age": 30}];

function getPerson(id) {
    for(var i=0, max = people.length;i<max;i++) {
        if(people[i].id === id) {
            return people[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you please be more specific what you mean to insert a Javascript array to my page? When and where should I do this?

Comment: @Rico - I added some sample code. This is just to give you an idea how an array of people objects could be declared in JavaScript and a function to find a person by id. You will have to adapt this to your own situation. The array of people is in the global scope. You may want to do this at the beginning of your script block.